# 2d array pointer not apply to both dimensions

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I'm new to C++ and I can't seem to wrap my head around accessing a 2d array from another class. This is my attempt so far but I'm confused. This is from what I've tried to gather online, but I don't understand for example, why the getter function is returning a char type, but in the form of a pointer?

Game Header

```
class Game {
 public:
    char (*getLevel())[28];
 private:
    char level[16][28];
}
```

Game.cpp

```
char (*Game::getLevel())[28] {
    return level;
}

pacman->moveEntity(getLevel(), pacman->getXPos(), pacman->getYPos(), direction);
```

Pacman.cpp

```
void Pacman::moveEntity(char level, int x, int y, char dir) {
     level[y][x] = ' ';
}
```

[y] is redlined, and says Expression must have pointer to object type

Comment: You have evidently gone out of your way to return a pointer from that function, and you're really asking us why the function returns a pointer?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is not the code that's failing.

Comment: Because argument `level` is a char, and you can't convert from a `char(*)[28]` to a `char`

Comment: Sigh, it's so hard for someone new to ask a question.

I mentioned the first part because I don't actually specify the type as char*. It's char but returns a pointer still

Comment: Good lord. What is with all the downvotes tonight? These people obviously come here for help. If you are simply here to cast downvotes or aspersions without providing any guidance, you are here for the wrong reasons. If you need more information or would like to suggest he comply with a rule, that can be done without downvote. If you cannot tell the difference between someone who is genuinely seeking help, and someone who is trying to game SO to finish an assignment, then you don't need to be here. We are here to help, not belittle. Remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `level` in the function signature must match the type you call it with, in this particular case `char level[][28]`.

Comment: Or `char (*level)[28]` if you want to write it in the same style.